# Apache Spark security.NosuchAlgorithm exception on changing from java 7 to java 8

Tags: apache-spark, java-8

I have a cluster (Hortonworks supported system) running Apache spark on 1.5.2 on Java 7, installed by admin. Java 8 is also installed.

I don't have admin access to this cluster and would like to run spark (1.5.2 and later versions) on java 8.

I come from HPC/MPI background. So I naively copied all executables of spark "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/" into my root folder.

When I run spark-shell from my copied folder, it runs as expected on java 7.

When I change $JAVA_HOME to point to java 8, and run spark-shell, I get the following error.

Could you please help me fix this error?

**Edit**: by comparing log output when using java 7 and java 8, it seems that this exception occurs when starting http server

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
        at org.apache.spark.SSLOptions.liftedTree1$1(SSLOptions.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.SSLOptions.<init>(SSLOptions.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.SSLOptions$.parse(SSLOptions.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.<init>(SparkIMain.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter.<init>(SparkILoop.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createInterpreter(SparkILoop.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:949)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:685)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:653)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:767)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
        ... 28 more
```